# Edit queries INTO a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a Stored Procedure to call in MySQL which receives 3 parameters. Any of them could be null. Now, if they are null I have to run an open query (without where statements) and if they are not, I have to apply constraints with the values that I receive. I give you my code here ;)

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `getPeople`(
IN p_startDate DATE,
IN p_endDate DATE,
IN p_name TEXT
)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM people;
    -- if p_startDate is not null, 'append' to the query "WHERE birthdate >= p_startDate"
    -- if p_endDate is not null, 'append' to the query "WHERE birthdate <= p_endDate"
    -- if p_name is not null, 'append' to the query "WHERE name = p_name"
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

My first approach is writing the 3 different queries, but I can't mix them (e.g.: p_startDate and p_endDate not null and I just want 1 query to be executed). Can you throw some light on me?

THANK YOU very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that prepared statements would be the way to go about this in MySQL (you could use dynamic SQL to achieve this in SQL server)

Have a look here:

[SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

You would put your main statement with no where clauses into one variable, then use whatever logic you require to append the where clauses you want onto that string and then prepare and execute a query from that.

The page above gives some examples that you should be able to adapt to meet your needs.

Comment: It went PERFECT. With SET and CONCAT I can append my where restrictions